# Passing numerical string with leading zero from asp.net razor to javascript - stange behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I'm using a javascript plug in to highlight text on my web page.

The funktion is simple:

```
  $("p").highlight("abc", true);
```

This is working perfect and highlights every occurence of 'abc' in every 'p' tag.

When I call the fkd this way in razor:

```
@{
    string markText = "abc";
}

<script>
  $("p").highlight(@markText, true);
</script>
```

It works also fine.

But when I set a numerical string with a leading zero e.g.:

```
@{
    string markText = "0123";
}
```

the javascript gets "83".

By the way I found out that 123 octal = 83 decimal.

So my question is how can I pass a string like "0123" straight forward to the javascript without transform?

Best regards
GertR

Comment: try `$("p").highlight("@markText", true);`

Comment: Thanks for that quick help, it's working perfect! I never expect that the solution is that easy... ;)